# How to allow an object to move within a collider?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, collision

I am trying to have a block that can only be pushed inside of a rectangular collider. The player has to be able to move through the collider in order to push the block. I have tried to affect the mass upon the block being pushed into the edge collider, the drag, the angular drag, the velocity, isKinematic but nothing will stop the cube from moving when it hits the collider. It is really confusing, any help would really be appreciated...Here is the code:

```
public class pushBlock2 : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody2D pBlock2;


    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "edge") {
            Debug.Log ("pushblock2 touched edge");
            pBlock2.isKinematic = true;
            pBlock2.isKinematic = false;
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "edge") {
            pBlock2.isKinematic = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did You tried using Bool and Trigger Exit. Rectangular collider mean ..?Are you using 4 colliders, is this 2d r 3d, furnish bit more in question or Screen Shot

Comment: I have tried using Trigger exit. It is an edge collider. This is a 2d top down game.

Comment: hi Jason@, as a new user be sure to tick the correct answer below, by Mokona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try and create four colliders around the area you want to move your block within? This way you'll have to stop the block from entering those which is much easier task than trying to prevent an item from leaving the collider.

I am pretty sure you will be able to pull this off without any code at all, you just need to setup a couple of static colliders to collide with objects on certain layer and put the cube you wanna move on that layer.

More info on Layer-based collisions can be found here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Comment: can I do that in a way that the player can walk over those colliders though?  I want the player to be able to move freely around over the colliders that are holding the movable block in said area.  My question isn't answered here.

Comment: Yes you would be able to do this. Be sure to check out this page on unity3d documentation, you are able to specify which layers can collide with each other. By placing the blocks on one layer and setting up the bounding boxes on another and removing collisions with player from the bounding box layer, you will achieve the desired result. Check out this docs page for more info: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood, you're trying to use the volume defined by a collider as a delimiter for movement. I'm supposing you also desire "realistic" collisions when the object attempts to go outside said volume. That being the case, I'm afraid it is not possible.

The whole physics simulation is made by assuming some rules. Whenever two colliders intersect, the physics follows the rule that two objects should not occupy the same space (just like the real world), and thus it will try to figure out how to separate them again.

You can somewhat work around this by using a set of colliders that defines an hollow object, such as a barrel or box, but its more likely you'll turn off physics simulation for the box and roll up your own algorithm if consistent behavior is needed.

Many things in games are actually "fake" behaviors. Perhaps you can achieve what you want by faking physics or faking collisions?